# Is there any way to truly disable ASP.NET Development Server?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

This thing is the bane of my existence, I hate it with all my heart.
Two Approaches I've seen here did not work for me:

1. In the properties pages of the web application, go to Web tab and choose 'Use Local IIS Server'
2. In the other properties (F4 on Project), set 'Always Start When Debugging' to false.

Still, when I attach my web application to the IIS process, it automatically starts the Dev server. If I use F5 to start my project, it always uses the Dev server.

This seems to happen every few months, where I'm simply unable to kill the Dev server in favor of IIS. Is there any way to just get rid of the thing? I don't see why it exists, and in my experience it's nearly impossible to debug with.

Edit: I do indeed have IIS, I use it constantly. I know my vDirs are all setup correctly, etc. It seems like something is completely overriding my settings to use IIS. Would manually deleting everything having to do with the dev server cause major issues? I'd rather see cryptic OS file not found messages than see that damn server pop up one more time.

Comment: Possibly a stupid question, but have you got IIS installed on your dev machine?!

Comment: have you looked at IIS Express?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald Yes, I have the IIS, all my virtual directories are added correctly, etc.

Comment: Few questions: Are there other developers working on this project?  If so, are y'all using source control?  If so, is Apply server settings to all users (store in project file) checked in the Web tab of the properties page for the project?  If it is checked, another developer on your team could be checking in his/her settings, which could be to use the dev server, and overriding your settings.  If that sounds like it is the case, uncheck that box.

Comment: Although it would warn you, have you tried running VS as an administrator. I'm finding on Win8 that if I don't run it as admin it won't run IIS Express for me :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out, and hope it helps someone else.

I have 4 different Web Applications in one solution. One Application was set to use the Development Server, the others for IIS. Even when starting an application set for IIS, the Dev server apparently gets started because some other project requires it (Note that in that circumstance, it was not possible to debug the desired application with either server) This is not always the case though. I could not pinpoint what exact conditions were necessary to debug with the IIS process vs the Dev server with that setup.

My advice, set ALL Web applications in the same solution to use the same Server type (Dev/IIS) or your results will be unpredictable and you may lose the ability to debug.